# $k \in \mathbb Z^{+}$. Prove that for all $n ≥ 2k^2$, $n! ≥ k^{n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

> **Proposition**
> $k \in \mathbb Z^{+}$. Then for all $n ≥ 2k^2$, $n! ≥ k^{n}$

My attempt:

> **Lemma 1**. $k \in \mathbb Z^{+}$. For all $n \in \mathbb N$, $(k^2 + n)! ≥ k^{2n}$

Proof: By induction.

**Base case:** $n = 0$.

$(k^2 + 0)! ≥ 1  = k^{2\cdot0} = k^{2n}$

**Induction step:**

Suppose

$$(k^2 + n)! ≥ k^{2n}$$

Then
$$\begin{align}(k^2 + n + 1)! = (k^2 + n)! \cdot (k^2 + n + 1) & ≥ k^{2n} \cdot  (k^2 + n + 1) \\
& ≥ k^{2n} \cdot k \\
& = k^{2n+1}
\end{align}$$

---

Back to the proposition:

By induction.

**Base case**: $n = 2k^{2}$.

Applying lemma $1$, we conclude that $(2k^{2})! ≥ k^{2k^{2}}$

**Induction step:**

Suppose

$$n! ≥ k^{n}$$

Then

$\begin{align}(n+1)! = n! \cdot (n+1) & ≥ k^{n} \cdot (n+1)\\
& ≥ k^{n} \cdot k \space \space \space (\text{because } n > k)\\
& = k^{n+1}\\
\end{align}$

$\Box$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake at the end of the proof of the lemma
\begin{eqnarray*}
(k^2 + n + 1)! = (k^2 + n)! \cdot (k^2 + n + 1) & ≥ k^{2n} \cdot  (k^2 + n + 1) \\
& ≥ k^{2n} \cdot \color{red}{k^2} \\
& = k^{2n+\color{red}{2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
& in the base case of the proposition, you could be clearer by saying ... Using $n=k^2$ in the lemma gives $(2k^{2})!  \geq k^{2k^{2}} $.